# Remove OSX shortcut to switch between spaces (ctrl + number shortcut)

Tags: macos, mac, spaces, mission-control

On MacOsX Lion (upgrade from Leopard).
Working with some 3d application, I would like to temporarily turn off the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[numberOfSpace]</kbd>.

I went to:

```
 Preferences > Keyboard > Mission Control
```

and unchecked every checkbox;
However, the shortcut is still active. I cannot find the place where it's defined.
I also tried

```
Preferences > Mission Control
```

and unchecked all checkboxes in the bottom section, but the shortcut still works.
Is there a way to set/unset those shortcuts ?

Comment: which key is the numberOfSpaces ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you've unchecked all of the boxes in [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yjjcw.png) picture?

Comment: @shub yes, I unchecked them all, Buscar웃 it is ^1, ^2, ^3, ^4, ...

Comment: That's quite weird because it should realy disable the shortcut...

Comment: @ling Can you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18765462/3541881)? It should override the controls. Although it is odd that System Prefs doesn't work...

Comment: @shub I've checked the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist file: the 118, 119 and 120 codes (which represents the ctrl + 1, ctrl + 2 and ctrl + 3 shortcuts according to this: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-114785.html) were already disabled, but I still can navigate through the spaces with those shortcuts !!

Comment: Four years too late, but the bug still seems to exist. I solved it by remapping ^1 to e.g. shift+^1 in the Mission Control key bindings. Then it should work whether disabled or not.

Answer (score 9):

Please check and uncheck accordingly

Go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Mission Control**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I already did that, and I even unchecked every checkboxes on the right section, but I can still navigate with ctrl + 1, ctrl + 2, ...